# How to invoke SFTP Output Endpoint using groovy component in Mule

Tags: groovy, mule, sftp, mule-component, mule-esb

I want to initialise SFTP Outbound Endpoint using Groovy component in Mule. Could someone suggest how to implement this

Comment: why can't you just use the SFTP connector? I'm confused at what you're asking

Comment: I have requirement to pass values dynamically to the SFTP Outbound Endpoint URL (like passphrase) which i cannot achieve through SFTP connector. Hence, want to invoke it through groovy component. For SFTP Inbound Endpoint, i am able to invoke it through Groovy component.